# How to avoid the endless loop and remove the definition?

Tags: functions, function-construction, expression-manipulation

The function

```
AnI[n_]:=(-((2 n ((R1/R2)^((2 \[Pi])/\[Beta]) - (R2/R1)^((
     2 \[Pi])/\[Beta])) \[Beta] Aki[
    2] (Sin[n theta1] - Sin[n (theta1 + \[Beta])]))/(
  R2 ((R1/R2)^((2 \[Pi])/\[Beta]) + (R2/R1)^((
     2 \[Pi])/\[Beta])) (4 \[Pi]^2 - n^2 \[Beta]^2))) - (
 n ((R1/R2)^(\[Pi]/\[Beta]) - (R2/R1)^(\[Pi]/\[Beta])) \[Beta] Aki[
   1] (Sin[n theta1] + Sin[n (theta1 + \[Beta])]))/(
 R2 ((R1/R2)^(\[Pi]/\[Beta]) + (R2/R1)^(\[Pi]/\[Beta])) (\[Pi] - 
    n \[Beta]) (\[Pi] + n \[Beta])));
```

This expression contains `Aki[n]`, for example `Aki[1]`, `Aki[2]`...

Another function is

```
Aki[k_]:=(\[Beta] ((2 R2 (R2/R3 + R3/R2) CnI[1])/((R2/R3 - R3/R2) \[Beta]) + (
    4 R3 DnI[1])/((-(R2/R3) + R3/R2) \[Beta])) (-\[Beta] Cos[
      theta1] + \[Beta] Cos[k \[Pi]] Cos[theta1 + \[Beta]] + 
    k \[Pi] Sin[k \[Pi]] Sin[
      theta1 + \[Beta]]))/((k \[Pi] - \[Beta]) (k \[Pi] + \[Beta])) + \
(\[Beta] ((2 R2 (R2/R3 + R3/R2) AnI[1])/((R2/R3 - R3/R2) \[Beta]) + (
    4 R3 BnI[1])/((-(R2/R3) + R3/R2) \[Beta])) (k \[Pi] Cos[
      theta1 + \[Beta]] Sin[
      k \[Pi]] + \[Beta] (Sin[theta1] - 
       Cos[k \[Pi]] Sin[
         theta1 + \[Beta]])))/((k \[Pi] - \[Beta]) (k \[Pi] + \
\[Beta])) + (\[Beta] ((
    R2 (R2^2/R3^2 + R3^2/R2^2) CnI[
      2])/((R2^2/R3^2 - R3^2/R2^2) \[Beta]) + (
    2 R3 DnI[
      2])/((-(R2^2/R3^2) + R3^2/R2^2) \[Beta])) (-2 \[Beta] Cos[
      2 theta1] + 2 \[Beta] Cos[k \[Pi]] Cos[2 (theta1 + \[Beta])] + 
    k \[Pi] Sin[k \[Pi]] Sin[2 (theta1 + \[Beta])]))/(
 k^2 \[Pi]^2 - 
  4 \[Beta]^2) + (\[Beta] ((
    R2 (R2^2/R3^2 + R3^2/R2^2) AnI[
      2])/((R2^2/R3^2 - R3^2/R2^2) \[Beta]) + (
    2 R3 BnI[2])/((-(R2^2/R3^2) + R3^2/R2^2) \[Beta])) (k \[Pi] Cos[
      2 (theta1 + \[Beta])] Sin[k \[Pi]] + 
    2 \[Beta] (Sin[2 theta1] - 
       Cos[k \[Pi]] Sin[2 (theta1 + \[Beta])])))/(
 k^2 \[Pi]^2 - 4 \[Beta]^2);
```

This expression contains `AnI[n]`, for example `AnI[1]`, `AnI[2]`...

**So if you want to get the equation of `AnI[n]` and `Aki[k]` in the same notebook, you have to remove the definition, otherwise it will fall into the endless loop, so how to remove the definition of `AnI[n]` and `Aki[k]` after I get their expression?**

For example, you can get the expression of `AnI[2]`,but I want to **remove the definition** of `AnI[2]` and `AnI[n]` after I get the expression, but it seems that `Remove[AnI[2]]` and `Remove[AnI[n]]` and `Remove[AnI[*]]` are all useless. So how to solve this?

**And if there is some good idea to solve with this situation, fox example I have to get the expression of `AnI[1]` and `AnI[2]`... in the first notebook and get the expression of `Aki[1]` and `Aki[2]`... in the second notebook and solve the equations with `AnI[1]` and `AnI[2]`... and `Aki[1]` and `Aki[2]`... in the third notebook. So is there any way to define and solve all in one notebook?**

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to the community. Use `ClearAll` (`ClearAll[AnI]`) to remove all the definitions of a symbol like `AnI[1], AnI[2], ... ` or `Unset` for a single case like: `Unset[AnI[1]]`.

Comment: @BenIzd, `ClearAll[AnI[n], AnI[2]]` can not work, and the hint is `ClearAll::ssym: AnI[n] is not a symbol or a string.` and `ClearAll::ssym: AnI[2] is not a symbol or a string.`

Comment: @BenIzd, and the `Unset` can not work as well, the hint is `Unset::norep: Assignment on AnI for AnI[n] not found.`

Comment: [`ClearAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClearAll.html) should be called with only the symbol name and it will clear all the existing definitions for that symbol like `ClearAll[AnI]`. On the `Unset` message, if you don't set any value and want to unset it, it'll raise a message as you've seen. You can suppress that with [`Quiet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quiet.html).

Comment: Dear @fhrl, your questions take a lot of effort to read. You should make it as simple as possible, so that one can very clearly understand what the actual question is. For example, do not use complicated equations if much simpler equations suffice to ask your question. Please become familiar with the idea of a minimal working example (MWE) as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @BenIzd，@user,thanks a lot for all your answers and suggestion！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce dummy variables {aki1,aki2,anI1,anI2} and solve for them.

```
AnI[n_] = (-((2 n ((R1/R2)^((2 \[Pi])/\[Beta]) - (R2/
               R1)^((2 \[Pi])/\[Beta])) \[Beta] Aki[
           2] (Sin[n theta1] - 
            Sin[n (theta1 + \[Beta])]))/(R2 ((R1/
               R2)^((2 \[Pi])/\[Beta]) + (R2/
               R1)^((2 \[Pi])/\[Beta])) (4 \[Pi]^2 - 
            n^2 \[Beta]^2))) - (n ((R1/R2)^(\[Pi]/\[Beta]) - (R2/
             R1)^(\[Pi]/\[Beta])) \[Beta] Aki[
         1] (Sin[n theta1] + 
          Sin[n (theta1 + \[Beta])]))/(R2 ((R1/
             R2)^(\[Pi]/\[Beta]) + (R2/R1)^(\[Pi]/\[Beta])) (\[Pi] - 
          n \[Beta]) (\[Pi] + n \[Beta]))) /. {Aki[1] -> aki1, 
    Aki[2] -> aki2};

Aki[k_] = (\[Beta] ((2 R2 (R2/R3 + R3/R2) CnI[
             1])/((R2/R3 - R3/R2) \[Beta]) + (4 R3 DnI[
             1])/((-(R2/R3) + R3/R2) \[Beta])) (-\[Beta] Cos[
           theta1] + \[Beta] Cos[k \[Pi]] Cos[theta1 + \[Beta]] + 
         k \[Pi] Sin[k \[Pi]] Sin[
           theta1 + \[Beta]]))/((k \[Pi] - \[Beta]) (k \[Pi] + \
\[Beta])) + (\[Beta] ((2 R2 (R2/R3 + R3/R2) AnI[
             1])/((R2/R3 - R3/R2) \[Beta]) + (4 R3 BnI[
             1])/((-(R2/R3) + R3/R2) \[Beta])) (k \[Pi] Cos[
           theta1 + \[Beta]] Sin[
           k \[Pi]] + \[Beta] (Sin[theta1] - 
            Cos[k \[Pi]] Sin[
              theta1 + \[Beta]])))/((k \[Pi] - \[Beta]) (k \[Pi] + \
\[Beta])) + (\[Beta] ((R2 (R2^2/R3^2 + R3^2/R2^2) CnI[
             2])/((R2^2/R3^2 - R3^2/R2^2) \[Beta]) + (2 R3 DnI[
             2])/((-(R2^2/R3^2) + 
              R3^2/R2^2) \[Beta])) (-2 \[Beta] Cos[2 theta1] + 
         2 \[Beta] Cos[k \[Pi]] Cos[2 (theta1 + \[Beta])] + 
         k \[Pi] Sin[k \[Pi]] Sin[
           2 (theta1 + \[Beta])]))/(k^2 \[Pi]^2 - 
       4 \[Beta]^2) + (\[Beta] ((R2 (R2^2/R3^2 + R3^2/R2^2) AnI[
             2])/((R2^2/R3^2 - R3^2/R2^2) \[Beta]) + (2 R3 BnI[
             2])/((-(R2^2/R3^2) + R3^2/R2^2) \[Beta])) (k \[Pi] Cos[
           2 (theta1 + \[Beta])] Sin[k \[Pi]] + 
         2 \[Beta] (Sin[2 theta1] - 
            Cos[k \[Pi]] Sin[2 (theta1 + \[Beta])])))/(k^2 \[Pi]^2 - 
       4 \[Beta]^2) /. {AnI[1] -> anI1, AnI[2] -> anI2};

soln = Solve[{anI1 == AnI[1] /. {aki1 -> Aki[1], aki2 -> Aki[2]}, 
   anI2 == AnI[2] /. {aki1 -> Aki[1], aki2 -> Aki[2]}}, {anI1, anI2}]

solk = Solve[{aki1 == Aki[1] /. {anI1 -> AnI[1], anI2 -> AnI[2]}, 
   aki2 == Aki[2] /. {anI1 -> AnI[1], anI2 -> AnI[2]}}, {aki1, aki2}
]
```

Didn't simplify, since it is quite slow.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and suggestion of dummy variables, but in fact I think it is not convenient to use this method as you have to replace some variables always, so is there any better way? For example, the local definition?